# My click infowindow does not change for nearby points.

Tags: carto

My cartoDB map has several observations/points and sometimes they are clustered. I have infowindows setup for each point and it displays when I click on them. The problem happens when these points are close to each other. The window will popup for the first chosen point, but unless I close it or zoom in[image] significantly, it will not automatically close and re-open for those nearby points when I click on them. It will work fine if I choose points located far away from each other. Please, any advice?

Comment: Can you share the link and CartoCSS code to your map? I was not able to replicate your issue using my own maps.

Comment: Hi sure, here is the link to the map: https://williamsmcastro.carto.com/builder/4b062d24-5600-41d5-a52d-9a9e0c57aa8a/embed?state=%7B%22map%22%3A%7B%22ne%22%3A%5B-56.752722872057355%2C-124.27734375000001%5D%2C%22sw%22%3A%5B39.095962936305476%2C-8.261718750000002%5D%2C%22center%22%3A%5B-13.2399454992863%2C-66.26953125000001%5D%2C%22zoom%22%3A3%7D%2C%22widgets%22%3A%7B%228688cd9f-fe77-4f04-aea9-bab0f169d99a%22%3A%7B%22normalized%22%3Atrue%7D%7D%7D

Comment: here is the CartoCss: #layer {
  marker-width: 6.5;
  marker-fill: #d56c4d;
  marker-fill-opacity: 1;
  marker-allow-overlap: true;
  marker-line-width: 1;
  marker-line-color: #FFF;
  marker-line-opacity: 1;
}

Comment: Ok, now I understand the issue. Going to answer you in a proper answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an expected behavior. CARTO uses [`UTFGrid`s to allow users to interact with the data displayed on the map](https://github.com/mapbox/utfgrid-spec), [as explained on CARTO Maps API docs](https://carto.com/docs/carto-engine/maps-api/anonymous-maps/#anonymous-maps). You can read how UTFGrid works [on this old Mapbox blogpost](https://blog.mapbox.com/how-interactivity-works-with-utfgrid-3b7d437f9ca9). Basically, it generates an invisible grid containing the data from the points which are located within that grid. So in your use case, you cannot interact with those points that are in the same UTFgrid:

[image: utfgrid]

You can check the points that share the same UTFGrid using the browser console. Because this is a expected behaviour, what you need to do is closing the infowindow and clicking again on another point.

Comment: Is there any way to reduce the size of the grid?

Comment: Unfortunately, that's not possible.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing much about cartodb and how it generates a popup, I recommend you to see it in chrome inspector. Perhaps the popup container is larger and rectangular (due to the arrow towards the element) which causes your 'click' event not being performed on the map/element.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I tried that but the problem persists. I think this is a cartodb issue.